# "Add to playlist" option gives a popup to create a channel on YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

YouTube will not let me add videos to playlists on my Chromebox. When I try to add something to a playlist, a page comes up to set up a channel. If I click on continue, nothing happens.

Is YouTube broken?

Answer (score 1):

[From the official help pages](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861):

> With just a Google Account, you can watch, like, and subscribe. Google Accounts don't come with a YouTube channel by default; without a channel, you have no public presence on YouTube.
>
> **To upload, comment, or make playlists, create a public YouTube channel.**

If that popup doesn't work, use either of these links: [create a Youtube channel with your name](https://www.youtube.com/create_channel) or [create a Youtube channel with another name](http://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher)